# Spring Transaction Performance Multiple Vs Single

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions

So I am curious in knowing what is the performance impact if we have a single transaction with multiple updates in one flow Or have separate transaction for each of the update.

If application can sustain both of the patterns which one is the best one to opt for. But in the case if application can only go with the second option which is to have different transactions for all the updates then how much kick back to do we get in terms of performance.

```
@Transactional 
public updateXYZ(){
 updateX()
 updateY()
 updateZ()
}
```

VS

```
public updateXYZ(){
 updateSeprateTransactionX()
 updateSeprateTransactionY()
 updateSeprateTransactionZ()
}
```

Comment: Simply measure it with a test setup!

Comment: Opening a connection and starting a transaction takes time, so you generally want a single one. Also you probably want a single one from a consistency pov. If hte last action fails what should happen to the first 2 actions?

Comment: If last one fail we should persist the first two. But if that comes up with a lot of performance cost then I can go with the idea of trying whole batch and put everything in a single transaction.

Comment: Transactions are not for free on the database side. So sometimes multiple short transactions are faster than single one that is huge. But as I said. Measure it.

Comment: Yes will try to measure using a test and will post if I found some thing interesting. It becomes more interesting if we have sort of multimaster database cluster like galera .